# LinqtoSql Pre-compile Query problem with Count() on a group by

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, precompiled

Have a LinqtoSql query that I now want to precompile.

```
var unorderedc =
            from insp in sq.Inspections
            where insp.TestTimeStamp > dStartTime && insp.TestTimeStamp < dEndTime
                && insp.Model == "EP" && insp.TestResults != "P"
            group insp by new { insp.TestResults, insp.FailStep } into grp

            select new
            {

                FailedCount = (grp.Key.TestResults == "F" ? grp.Count() : 0),
                CancelCount = (grp.Key.TestResults == "C" ? grp.Count() : 0),
                grp.Key.TestResults,
                grp.Key.FailStep,
                PercentFailed = Convert.ToDecimal(1.0 * grp.Count() / tcount * 100)

            };
```

I have created this delegate:

```
public static readonly Funct<SQLDataDataContext, int, string, string, DateTime, DateTime, IQueryable<CalcFailedTestResult>>
    GetInspData = CompiledQuery.Compile((SQLDataDataContext sq, int tcount, string strModel, string strTest, DateTime dStartTime,
    DateTime dEndTime, IQueryable<CalcFailedTestResult> CalcFailed) =>
    from insp in sq.Inspections
            where insp.TestTimeStamp > dStartTime && insp.TestTimeStamp < dEndTime
                && insp.Model == strModel && insp.TestResults != strTest
            group insp by new { insp.TestResults, insp.FailStep } into grp
            select new 
            {
                FailedCount = (grp.Key.TestResults == "F" ? grp.Count() : 0),
                CancelCount = (grp.Key.TestResults == "C" ? grp.Count() : 0),
                grp.Key.TestResults,
                grp.Key.FailStep,
                PercentFailed = Convert.ToDecimal(1.0 * grp.Count() / tcount * 100)
            });
```

The syntax error is on the CompileQuery.Compile() statement

It appears to be related to the use of the select new {} syntax.
In other pre-compiled queries I have written I have had to just use the select projection by it self.  In this case I need to perform the grp.count() and the immediate if logic.

I have searched SO and other references but cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you can't have a CompliedQuery for an anonymous type, you need to have the query return a named type, so your

```
select new 
        {
            FailedCount = (grp.Key.TestResults == "F" ? grp.Count() : 0),
            CancelCount = (grp.Key.TestResults == "C" ? grp.Count() : 0),
            grp.Key.TestResults,
            grp.Key.FailStep,
            PercentFailed = Convert.ToDecimal(1.0 * grp.Count() / tcount * 100)
        }
```

Would now be:

```
select new MyType
        {
            FailedCount = (grp.Key.TestResults == "F" ? grp.Count() : 0),
            CancelCount = (grp.Key.TestResults == "C" ? grp.Count() : 0),
            TestResults = grp.Key.TestResults,
            FailStep = grp.Key.FailStep,
            PercentFailed = Convert.ToDecimal(1.0 * grp.Count() / tcount * 100)
        }
```

The last generic param of your `Func<>` would be `IQueryable<MyType>` as well, since that's what your query would now return.

In this case, `MyType` would look something like:

```
public class MyType {
  public int FailedCount { get; set; }
  public int CancelCount { get; set; }
  public string TestResults { get; set; }
  public string FailStep { get; set; } //Unsure of type here
  public decimal PercentFailed { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nick,  This worked but there appears to be a limit to the number of types you can pass to a compiled query.

I had to do much more digging to sort this one out.

http://omaralzabir.com/solving_common_problems_with_compiled_queries_in_linq_to_sql_for_high_demand_asp_net_websites/

Once I fixed this problem the query compiled just fine.